# How to solve the differential equation $y' = \frac{-x-y}{x+2y}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve the differential equation $y' = \frac{-x-y}{x+2y}$?

---

[My Attempt.]
Setting $u=\frac{y}{x}$, I got
$$
\frac{(1+2u)u'}{2u^2+2u+1} = -\frac{1}{x},
$$
which seems to be not very helpful. What should be the next step?

Comment: Get the RHS as a function of $u$ at first, then express $y^{'} $ as a function of $u^{'}, x , u$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach to solving
$$
y'=\frac{-x-y}{x+2y}
$$
We can double and add $1$ to get
$$
1+2y'=\frac{-x}{x+2y}
$$
Then, multiplying by $x+2y$, we have
$$
(x+2y)\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x+2y)=-x
$$
integration and algebra yield
$$
(x+2y)^2+x^2=C
$$

Comment: 2x^2+4xy+4y^2=C → 4x+4y+8yy'=0 → x+y+2yy'=0  what should be the next step?

Comment: would you teach me how to prove this?

Comment: $(x+2y)\,\mathrm{d}(x+2y)=-x\,\mathrm{d}x\implies\frac12(x+2y)^2=-\frac12x^2+C$

Comment: I understand. thank you so much.

Comment: @S.Ky: I have incorporated that into the answer to clarify. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am starting from where you left off (Not checking the steps upto this one)

$$ \int{\frac{(1+2u)du}{2u^2+2u+1}}=\int{-\frac{dx}{x}} $$

Put $$2u^2+2u+1=t$$

$$(2+4u)du=dt$$

$$(1+2u)du=\frac{dt}{2}$$

Substitute and solve.

**EDIT:**

This gives us,

$$\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{dt}{t}}=-\int{\frac{dx}{x}}$$

$$\log{t}=-2\log{x}+C_1$$

$$\log{(tx^2)}=C_1$$

$$tx^2=C_2$$

$$(2u^2+2u+1)x^2=C_2$$

$$(2\frac{y^2}{x^2}+2\frac{y}{x}+1)x^2=C_3$$

$$2y^2+2xy+x^2=D$$

Comment: @S.Ky check the complete solution

Comment: log|t|=-2log|x|+c1 → log|t|+2log|x|=c1 → t*x^2=c2 → (2y^2/x^2+2y/x+1)x^2=c2 → 2y^2+2xy+x^2=c2  Correct?

Comment: @S.Ky Oh yes. Sorry for the mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: @S.Ky Yes, and see if you obtain the given equation.

Answer (score 0):

The substitution of $u=\tfrac{y}{x}$ was a good choice and you arrived at:

> $\frac{(1+2u)u'}{2u^2+2u+1} = -\frac{1}{x}$
>
> what should be the next step?

This differential equation is separable, so:

$$\int \frac{\color{green}{2u+1}}{\color{blue}{2u^2+2u+1}} \,\mbox{d}u = -\int\frac{1}{x}\,\mbox{d}x$$
Now note that:
$$\left(\color{blue}{2u^2+2u+1}\right)'=4u+2 = 2(\color{green}{2u+1})$$
so you could proceed with setting $t=\color{blue}{2u^2+2u+1}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @S.Ky Yes; I'd write: $\tfrac{1}{2}\log t = -\log x +c$, so $\log\sqrt{t} = \log\tfrac{1}{x}+c$, so $\sqrt{t}=\tfrac{C}{x}$; now you could go back to $u$ and then $y$.